# Solve this equation : $(2x)! = (x)! (x+2)!$

Tags: calculus, factorial, gamma-function

Solve  this  equation  :

$(2x)!  =  (x)!    (x+2)!$

Comment: [WolframAlpha is that way](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%282x%29%21%3D%28x%29%21%28x%2B2%29%21). This is Math.SE, and it's much more likely you'll get answers if you start by explaining the context of this question and what you attempted so far to solve it.

Comment: The only solution of $$ \frac{1}{x+1}\binom{2x}{x}=x+2 $$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$ is given by $x=3$. The LHS grows way faster than the RHS for big $x$, and both are convex functions.

Comment: Are you sure you want all complex solutions and not just non-negative integer ones (after seeing the tags you insist on using)?

Answer (score 4):

If $x\ge 4$, $$\begin{align}(x+1)(x+2)&=\frac{(x+1)(x+2)(2x)!}{(x+2)!x!}\\&={2x\choose x}\\&>{2x\choose3}\\&=\frac{2x(2x-1)(2x-2)}{6}\\&\ge\frac x3(x+3)(x+2)\end{align}$$ 
quickly leads to a contradiction.
Manually check all cases with $x\le 3$.